# Bootstrap thumbnail image size increases when a larger image is being used

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap thumbnail class to create a list like this

[image]

Its working fine and the size of the image am using there is 1360*768.

I tried to change the image to another one of size 4128x2322  which caused a problem as below.

[image]

Here as you can see its not showing as a thumbnail when I used larger image and it looks like it breakes the grid structure too. Hope you notice the hscroll.

So Bootstrap thumbnail is not adjusts with the column its being placed?

Here is my HTML markup

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-6 question-options">

        <div class="row individual ">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 match-left-column-options image-column ">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="http://myurl/images/match_20151118150735474_PJFYFTPZVL.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Left option1</h4>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 arrow-column"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-5x"></i></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 arrow-column"><i class="fa fa-caret-left fa-5x"></i></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 match-right-column-options image-column">
                 <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="http://myurl/images/match_20151118150735474_PJFYFTPZVL.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Right Option1</h4>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>




    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I create your example in jsFiddle with '2560 × 1440' image and '1920 × 1080' image but it seems Ok.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/be4r0p82/1/)

I think it is about your bootstrap version or you need to look other parents of this thumbnail class. Maybe here is a padding or margin!

In these case when you use `img{width:%100}` it will fit column.

It is about your classes you should delete width or height in "**match-left-column-options**" or "**image-column**" or "**match-right-column-options**".

Comment: Thats true.. Everything getting fit in the column except the Thumbnail thing... Thanks for that info.. Will check in detail on the parent elements.

Comment: @sforsandeep I think you need to look "match-right-column-options" and "image-column" class. If you give width or height it will destroy your structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-6 question-options">

    <div class="row individual ">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 match-left-column-options image-column ">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="Image/1.png" class="img-thumbnail">
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>Left option1</h4>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 arrow-column"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-5x"></i></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 arrow-column"><i class="fa fa-caret-left fa-5x"></i></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 match-right-column-options image-column">
             <div class="thumbnail">
                <img alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail" src="Image/1.png" class="img-thumbnail">
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>Right Option1</h4>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I think code will help you, Check this!!!